# Run a separate process with JXA and daemon

Tags: javascript, macos, automation, daemon, javascript-automation

I have a **JXA (JavaScript for Automation)** script that needs to perform a series of actions. Among these actions, it needs to activate **caffeinate** in a separate process and then continue with the rest of the code, allowing the secondary process to run until it is terminated by another command. Unfortunately, this only works when executed from the terminal or the script editor on a Mac and not when launched from the **.plist** daemon.

When I run:

```bash
bash -c "nohup caffeinate -u -i -d &"
```

from the terminal, the process is created, and I can close the terminal or terminate it with:

```bash
killall caffeinate
```

While I can start and stop it from the script editor as:

```js
var app = Application.currentApplication()
app.includeStandardAdditions = true


var accountUser = "Username";
var myPassword = "Password";

var caffeinateCommand = `bash -c "nohup /usr/bin/caffeinate -u -i -d &"`;
var returnedValue = app.doShellScript(caffeinateCommand, {userName:accountUser, password:myPassword, administratorPrivileges:true});

//
//
// Other Code
//
//

app.doShellScript("killall caffeinate");
```

When I try to start this same script as a daemon using a .plist file and execute it with **launchctl load /path/.plist**, the separate process is not created (in fact, instead of returning an empty value, it returns true, and when I run **killall caffeinate**, it says there are no active processes).

How can I ensure that this process gets started?

**NOTE:** I've noticed that the error should be in the execution of **nohup** within the daemon, but I don't know how to replace it. Because when I launch only **caffeinate**, the process remains on the main one and does not continue with the rest of the code.